# How to send a JS game using a Discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord

I have made a JavaScript game. Now I want to make a Discord bot that embeds it in a message, so a reader can click on the embed to play the game inside the chat. [Something similar to this Snake game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tk5c0t72Up4&list=PLL7ab2XZ_GU2lqe2tGiBtpeb5knl_loJY&index=2).

Here's what the result should look like:

[image]

Comment: The game shown in the video is coded in JavaScript but is run on the bot _server_, not on the client. The bot appears to compose an HTML response which is then sent to the client, which is then displayed. They don't "send a JavaScript game". I doubt Discord will ever allow sending actual JavaScript to be executed on the client. So I don't think what I think you think you want to do is feasible.

Comment: well, is there anything else I can do?

Comment: You could try to re-write your game the way both of these folks show in their videos, strictly by using Discord's API, or as it's been suggested on your SO question, host your game on the web, outside of Discord.

Comment: ok how could I host it on a website

Comment: and what website platform

Comment: Now we are outside the realm of game development questions, and into the realm of general web development. There are way more web developers than game developers, so you'll be able to find answers to your hosting queries elsewhere. Try searching for "where to host a web game" or something similar and see what hits you get. We don't do platform recommendations here, because anything we advise will quickly become less up-to-date than the fresh-off-the-presses results you get from your own web search.

Comment: ok thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really send a game through Discord unless you are using Discord's API.

Why?

> The game shown in the video is coded in JavaScript but is run on the bot server, not on the client. The bot appears to compose an HTML response which is then sent to the client, which is then displayed. They don't "send a JavaScript game". I doubt Discord will ever allow sending actual JavaScript to be executed on the client.

(Vaillancourt told me)

But you can run it in a browser by hosting your game on itch.io and sharing a link to its itch.io page.

Comment: Don't worry, it's not weird to answer your own question here.